# Is it possible to group by certain values?

Tags: oracle10g

i have an oracle database table with following values

```
+------+--------+
| id   | Name   |
+------+--------+
|    0 | One    |
|    1 | Two    |
|    2 | Three  |
|    3 | four   |
|    4 | One    |
|    5 | One    |
|    6 | Two    |
|    7 | five   |
+------+--------+
```

i would like to count the number of rows having names 'One','Two',Rest of Names.
the result set should be like

```
+------+--------+
| name | count  |
+------+--------+
|  One | 3      |
+------+--------+
|  Two | 2      |
+------+--------+
|  Rest| 3      |
+------+--------+
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
  case name
    when 'One' then 'One'
    when 'Two' then 'Two'
    else 'Rest'
  end name,
  count(*)
from
  my_table
group by
  case name
    when 'One' then 'One'
    when 'Two' then 'Two'
    else 'Rest'
  end
```

Avoiding repetition:

```
select
  name,
  count(*)
from (
  select
    case name
      when 'One' then 'One'
      when 'Two' then 'Two'
      else 'Rest'
    end name
  from
    my_table)
group by
  name
```

Comment: I'd go with Case rather than Decode() -- it's ANSI compliant, more flexible, features short-circuit evaluation, and deals with nulls in a more SQL-consistent sense.